# C allocation memory

Tags: c, malloc

I'm a beginner on C, and I'm with a bug, the code bellow in some point stops the application during the runtime.

```
int l = 0;
//block 1
char *primaryIPaddr;
unsigned char *primaryIPaddrSize;
primaryIPaddrSize = *(unsigned char *) &msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimarySize: %u\n", primaryIPaddrSize);
if(primaryIPaddrSize != NULL) {
  memcpy ( primaryIPaddr, &msg[l], primaryIPaddrSize );
  AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryAddr: %s\n", primaryIPaddr);
  l += primaryIPaddrSize;
}
//block 2
char *secondaryIPaddr;
unsigned char *secondaryIPaddrSize;
secondaryIPaddrSize = *(unsigned char *) &msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "secondarySize: %u\n", secondaryIPaddrSize);
if(secondaryIPaddrSize != NULL) {
  memcpy ( secondaryIPaddr, &msg[l], secondaryIPaddrSize );
  AddToLog(logInfo, "secondaryAddr: %s\n", secondaryIPaddr);
  l += secondaryIPaddrSize;
}
//block 3
unsigned int *primaryPort;
unsigned int *secondaryPort;
primaryPort = *(unsigned int *) &msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "primaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
secondaryPort = *(unsigned int *) &msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "secondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);`
```

The msg variable it's a char filled by a UDP packet, I don't know what is wrong with my code, but when the process get to the block 2 it just stops, sounds like a memory problem, sinceI remove the block 1 and advance the l variable to the exactly point of the block 2, the block 2 process and dump correctly, just like the block 1 before the block 2 stops the process. So the code itself it's ok, seems like I'm not allocating memory properly, I tried to use malloc, but didn't do any effect so, I don't know what I'm not doing right, someone know the answer of what could be happening here?

The UDP packet comes this way:

```
UINT8 primaryIPaddrSize;
UINT8* primaryIPaddr; primaryIPaddrSize bytes
UINT8 secondaryIPaddrSize;
UINT8* secondaryIPaddr; secondaryIPaddrSize bytes
UINT16 primaryIPport;
UINT16 secondaryIPport`
```

The secondaryIp it's optional, so if the secondaryIPaddrSize is null, than I must jump secondaryIPaddr.`

Comment: Would you care to re-format your code ?

Comment: indents are your friend ;)

Comment: You are copying data into `primaryIPaddr` but you never allocated any space for it (and again on the second block). What does "I tried to use malloc" mean? You *need* to use `malloc` to allocate some space.

Comment: A better description of the UDP packet would have been `UINT8 primaryIPaddr[primaryIPaddrSize] ; variable length`. It is not a *pointer* but an array of undeterminate length. This cannot be expressed in a C struct, so one can solve it by using your notation. However, that is only one possible *implementation*.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'block 1' has a couple of problems.  You need to turn on your compiler warnings, or pay attention to those it is giving you.

```
char *primaryIPaddr;
unsigned char *primaryIPaddrSize;
primaryIPaddrSize = *(unsigned char *) &msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimarySize: %u\n", primaryIPaddrSize);
if (primaryIPaddrSize != NULL) {
    memcpy(primaryIPaddr, &msg[l], primaryIPaddrSize );
    AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryAddr: %s\n", primaryIPaddr);
    l += primaryIPaddrSize;
}
```

Your 'primaryIPaddrSize' is a `char *` (address), yet in the `memcpy()`, you use it as a length.  The assignment to `primaryIPaddrSize` is odd; you should be getting a warning about assigning a `char` to a pointer.  Given the assignment, the `memcpy()` length is 'OK', but it is all weird.  You should be writing:

```
unsigned char primaryIPaddrSize = msg[l++];
```

The other problem (that I'm going to diagnose — there are probably others) is that your `memcpy()` is copying to indeterminate memory.  You've not initialized `primaryIPaddr`, so it could point anywhere in memory.

You must always make sure you know where the data is going to be stored. Arguably, you need:

```
char *primaryIPaddr = malloc(primaryIPaddrSize);
```

followed by a memory check.

```
char *primaryIPaddr;
unsigned char primaryIPaddrSize = msg[l++];
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimarySize: %u\n", primaryIPaddrSize);
char *primaryIPaddr = NULL;
if (primaryIPaddrSize != 0)
{
    primaryIPaddr = malloc(primaryIPaddrSize);
    if (primaryIPaddr == 0)
        ...handle out of memory...
    memcpy(primaryIPaddr, &msg[l], primaryIPaddrSize );
    AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryAddr: %s\n", primaryIPaddr);
    l += primaryIPaddrSize;
}
```

The problems in Block 2 are pretty much symmetric with those in Block 1, but you've already wrecked the system by copying data to an unknown location.  The code in Block 3 doesn't need the pointers, again.  Also, port numbers are usually 2 bytes (0..65535), but your code only appears to handle 1 byte port numbers (so you won't be supporting HTTPS, amongst other services).

Comment: First, thanks a lot, I had spent so much time trying to solve this, I'm trying to learn C, indeed this was pretty much a beginner coding error. I still have a lot to look into it. Somethings I still don't get it,  why PrimaryIPaddr needs cursor and malloc,and the others don't? Why the msg variable needs the "&" clause to be storage on primaryIPaddr? Why I can't just do this too?

`primaryIPaddr = msg[l++]`

Comment: Just for noting, primaryIPaddrSize it's not a sizeof but a strlen of characters on the string. The primaryIPaddr is '****.**.255.6' and the primaryIpaddrSize is '12', So I think you might misunderstood, I had to change your example to work (I show you on the next comment).

I need it to added primaryIPaddrSize+1 on memcpy to get the correct value, I'm not sure, but I think it's about the \0 character that ends the string.

About the 1 byte port, I thought that an unsigned int was 2 bytes long.

Comment: unsigned char primaryIPaddrSize = msg[l++];
    AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimarySize: %u\n", primaryIPaddrSize);
    char *primaryIPaddr = NULL;
    if (primaryIPaddrSize != 0)
    {
        primaryIPaddr = malloc(32);
        if (primaryIPaddr == 0) {
          AddToLog(logError, "PrimaryAddr: Out of memory\n");
        }
        memcpy(primaryIPaddr, &msg[l++], primaryIPaddrSize+1 );
        AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryAddr: %s\n", primaryIPaddr);
        l += primaryIPaddrSize;
    }

Comment: For the port, I'm obligated to cast to unsigned int in order to get the correct value, other wise I get different values.
    unsigned int primaryPort = msg[l++];
    AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
    unsigned int secondaryPort = msg[l++];
    AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);

//Show wrong values
PrimaryPort: 117
SecondaryPort: 23

Comment: unsigned int primaryPort = *(unsigned int *) &msg[l++];
    AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
    unsigned int secondaryPort = *(unsigned int *) &msg[l++];
    AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);

//Show right values, almost
PrimaryPort: 6005
SecondaryPort: 654311447

Oddly SecondaryPort should it be zero.

Comment: Hi; please edit your question and add the new material into an addendum to it.  Leave the original alone, and add the new information suitably formatted.  As you can see, the formatting in comments is minimal, and I'm sorry, but I'm not going to try to read the code in your comments above.  It's bad enough when I have to write code in comments (I don't like doing it much), but you've got the opportunity edit the question and get it done so it is legible.  Please delete your comments above when you've edited the question, then add a new comment to drag me back again.  Thanks.